# Save resized image in created new subfolder

Tags: image-resizing

I have writen this following python script for resize image which size larger than 5MB.
However, I can't save the resized image into the new path. (saved at outisde the target folder)
Can anyone tell me how to midify the script?

Many Thanks

```
import os, sys
import PIL
import glob
import shutil
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from pathlib import Path

#define source and target directory 
dir_path = Path(r'D:\resize_python\test\StaticFilePath')
target_dir = Path(r'D:\resize_python\test\StaticFilePath\target_dir')

#copy the source folders to target directory
def ignore_files(dir, files):
    return [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, f))]

shutil.copytree(dir_path,
                target_dir,
                ignore=ignore_files)
..
..
..
..
..
ignore details

                        if (new_asp_rat == asp_rat):
                            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS);
                            img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img);
    
                            # adjusts the height to match the width
                            # NOTE: if you want to adjust the width to the height, instead ->
                            # uncomment the second line (new_width) and comment the first one (new_height)
                        else:
                            new_height = round(new_width / asp_rat);
                            #new_width = round(new_height * asp_rat);
                            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS);
                                                    
                        if img_extension.upper() == 'PNG':
                            print('png deteced')
                            img.save(os.path.join(dst_foldername, filename + '_resized.png'), 'PNG', quality=50, exif=exif)
                        else:
                            img.save(os.path.join(dst_foldername, filename + '_resized.jpeg'), 'JPEG', quality=50, exif=exif)
                            print(f'resized {filename}.{img_extension}')
```

shutil, os.path, os.join

The problem seems cause in img.save(os.path.join(dst_foldername, filename + '_resized.jpeg'), so may I know shouldn't I use other os.path.dirname rather os.path.join?